# Dry brown stem on tomato plant

Tags: plant-health, tomatoes

I carefully transferred this tomato from a pot because some of the leaves are starting to dry out and the stem is turning brown, and it did not seem to make a difference. So I was wondering if this is normal or is this tomato plant starting to die out?

**EDIT:** Updated with better image.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you would, if possible, list the conditions you are growing your tomato plant in e.g. temperature range, fertiliser, humidity e.t.c.

Comment: Conditions are normal tropical conditions, 27 to 30 degrees C, summer/dry and nearing rainy seasons. No fertilizer applied but a few kitchen scraps (onion peels, used coffee grounds) being mixed into the soil close to it. The plant was given to us in a 1 gallon plastic water bottle.

Answer (score 2):

I really cant get a good read based on the photo. If the tomatoes branch is turning brown more than likely your plant has some issues. Sclerotinia Stem Rot is a common issue and that might be what is going on here. However, it could also be timber rot. Lucky for you there is something you can use to fix this if this is the case at your local hardware store you can pick up something called rot stop that could very well fix the issue. However, because the picture is out of focus I can not confirm that it is rot. If the picture comes into focus and those are brown lumps then odds are it is a virus or bug which is handled in a different way. If I were in your positon I would find some stems with some green in them and put them in some water so that they will grow just incase you lose the plant. Best case more tomatoes.

Comment: Thanks for the initial suggestions, will try those and will also be posting a better photo tomorrow, sorry about that. For now the brown is not in patches but the whole stem from the bottom up to a point, sort of like a young stem going through its hardening/maturing stages.